# How to get latest entry among multiple models - django python

Tags: python, django

I have a model:

```
class Library(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField()

class Book(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField()
  lib = models.ForeignKey(Library,related_name="lib_books")
  added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

class Journal(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField()
  lib = models.ForeignKey(Library,related_name="lib_journals")
  added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

class Newspaper(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField()
  lib = models.ForeignKey(Library,related_name="lib_newspapers")
  added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

I am in the Library `BIG LIBRARY`. I want to know the last media(be it book,journal or newspaper) which came into this library recently.

How can I do this? I am thinking about how to do this so i didnot try anything yet.. please help

Comment: Why are these separate models? So far they have the same attributes. Perhaps you should store them as a Publication (or something) and have a `type` attribute that is Book/Newspaper/Journal, or have those inherit from this class?

Comment: @DavidRobinson in reality, they are not in this form. i just oversimplified them to make my question simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [latest()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest) to find the latest `book`, `journal` and `newspaper` and then find the maximum between them by `added` date:

```
from operator import attrgetter

book = Book.objects.latest('added')
journal = Journal.objects.latest('added')
newspaper = Newspaper.objects.latest('added')

print max((book, journal, newspaper), key=attrgetter('added'))
```

Note that if there is no records found by `latest()` it would throw `DoesNotExist` exception - you probably want to handle it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @doniyor great! But pay attention to the note I've added to the end of the answer.